# How to restore original entry point of a windows executable?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, portable-executable

I am trying to learn how to modify windows PE and make a packer. What I currently do is take an exe file, add a new section to it and change the oep to that new section. Where that new section only does is jump back to the original address of the file. Here is the code of the new section:

```
__asm {
    pushad
        mov eax, 0x0044F125 //oep
        jmp eax
}
```

As you can see I have to hard code the oep address. Is there any way I can either store the oep or calculate it?

Comment: Why would you want to calculate it? It is static? And how would you calculate it? What would be the inputs to your proposed calculation?

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not proper but all i want to know is how to find the oep back

Comment: when you have changed the oep you have changed it. AFAIK it's only stored once (in the extended header).

Comment: This is the thing i saw some file injectors and all they change the oep even upx does it but all of them at the end change it back how??
http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/33006-detailed-guide-to-pe-infection/

Comment: Either they remember the value, or they use magic to recover it.

Comment: please view my answer

Answer (score 1):

First the Entry Point of a PE File is in the headers, in summary the PE format contain:

- MZ Header (for compatibility purpose, but contain the offset of the PE Header).
- PE Header (contain info about the file, how many sections, imports, etc...). Containing the: File Header, Optional Header (this is the header that contain the Entry Point of the PE File.
- Section Headers
- Section Data

More info about PE:

- [Microsoft PE COFF Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg463119.aspx)
- [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)
- [corkami website](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE), very good info about the specifics of binary format, specially of the PE format.

If you want to do a packer you would need to:

1. Walk the PE headers structures to locate the original Entry Point
2. Saved and updated with the new entry point
3. Add the info of the newly added section.

The point 2 and 3 could do it in any order in case you do the point 2 first, you would need to known where the section could be located, it's easily calculated reading the existing sections. If you do the point 3 first, you already know the new entry point.

If you want you could look into [UPX packer](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) for more tips about how to modify the PE format and how to do a packer in general.

Comment: Please view my answer

Answer (score 0):

The OEP is stored in the PE file as an RVA. You modify that value, at which point the original value is lost. If you want to obtain the original value you must read it, and remember it, before modifying the value.

Comment: Please view my answer

Comment: What does it offer? It's exactly as we told you. Read the original value, and remember it.

Comment: I didn't edit my answer. I'm not quite sure why you asked the question. Anyway, never mind.

Comment: aah crap the other guy edited sorry i am really going mad with this stuff

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found it the actually write the oep in the file itself like this:

```
void write_stub_entry_point(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_headers, void *stub_addr) {
    if (stub_addr != NULL) {
        const char *signature = "\xFF\xEE\xDD\xCC";
        unsigned int index = 0;
        while (memcmp(((unsigned char *)stub_addr + index), signature, sizeof(int)) != 0) {
            ++index;
        }
        DWORD old_protections = 0;
        VirtualProtect(((unsigned char *)stub_addr + index), sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old_protections);
        memcpy(((unsigned char *)stub_addr + index), &nt_headers->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint, sizeof(DWORD));
        VirtualProtect(((unsigned char *)stub_addr + index), sizeof(DWORD), old_protections, NULL);
    }
}
```

now they only recover it from the file like this:

```
__asm { //Epilogue, stub exit point
    mov eax, target_image_base
        add eax, 0xCCDDEEFF     //Signature to be replaced by original entry point (OEP)
        mov esp, ebp
        mov[esp + 0x20], eax     //Store OEP in EAX through ESP to preserve across popad
        pop ebp
        popad                   //Restore thread context, with OEP in EAX
        jmp eax                 //Jump to OEP
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what we told you.